# Update homescreen widget with Async Task from which method?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-asynctask

I have the main app download an image to a folder on the mobile device, then the widget service grabs that image on the half hour and updates the widget imageview. I would like to turn this around. I'd like to parse the image within the widget service and then save the image to the device and have the main app pull it from the folder since the widget is updating and also the first thing the user sees of this app.

Currently my service just gets the file and puts it into a view. I would like to parse the xml within the service, but I keep getting the on network thread exception. Where do I run this Async task? in onStart(), onResume(), or?

```
onStart() / onResume / elsewhere? {
//other code...
new MyAsyncTask.execute();

}

public MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<>{

//parse the url

}
```

Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you add an Action to the appwidget receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".YourWidget" android:label="My Widget">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="your.package.name.MANUEL_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you send a broadcast which will trigger the receiver:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("your.package.name.MANUEL_UPDATE");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Inside the appwidets receiver you do the work you need to do with your new image!
Hope that helps.